Error Message On Mail Report Cron Job
This past weekend, we switched our hosting of CIVICRM from Siteground to Linode.  Now, when we run the Mail Report CRON job, we are getting the following error. It appears that it is having difficulty finding a DB, but unsure where to look.
Mail Reports
Entity: Job Action: mail_report
Summary
Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: unknown error
Details
Parameters raw (from db settings):
instanceId=33
Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
a:2:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:2:"33";}
Full message:
Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: unknown error

Can you check more details about the unknown error in civi log?
